# "WISO mein Büro" API doesnt work or it is my fault

Tags: php, api

unfortunately I get no good response from the api provider.
No I need your support. I build a test extension in "wiso mein büro" for testing.

I would like to create an order with php and this api:
https://api.meinbuero.de/openapi/documentation/#/orders/postorderCreate

My code:

```
$wisoApiKey         = "XXX";
$wisoSecretApiKey   = "XXX";
$wisoOwnershipId    = "XXX";    

$positionen[] = array ('id' => 769541, 'amount' => 60);
    
$ch = curl_init('https://api.meinbuero.de/openapi/order/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json" , "Authorization: Bearer ".$wisoToken));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $wisoApiKey . ":" . $wisoSecretApiKey);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(
    array (
        "customerId" => 1698487,
        "articles" => $positionen
    )
));
    
$createOrder = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
    

echo '<pre>';
print_r($createOrder);
```

Result:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx/1.19.0
Date: Mon, 09 Aug 2021 18:38:49 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains; preload
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

All other apis works fine like create, get customer, create invoice from order, ...
Only the api create order doesn't work for me.

I don't know why ...

Comment: 500 error typically means that the server has a bug. This should probably be a support question for your vendor.

Comment: okay - do you mean that is not my fault?

Comment: You should really not share your API keys and secrets. Everyone can use them now, and they can't be fully erased. Time to get new keys.

Comment: Yes, 500 = server error. In this scenario you are a client, not a server.

Comment: this are demo keys. no problem ;)

Comment: `$wisoToken` is not defined.

Comment: its defined, but I forgot to post it :/